# Inequality regarding positive real numbers

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function, real-numbers

I would like to show that the inequality
$$ \biggl(\frac{a}{a+b}\biggr)^c \le \frac{a+\frac{b}{2}}{a + \frac{b}{2} + bc}$$
holds for all $a,b,c>0$. So far I've only been able to deal with the case that $a\ge 1$ and $b,c>0$, using the Bernoulli inequality in the denominator:

$$ \biggl(\frac{a}{a+b}\biggr)^c = \frac{1}{(1+b/a)^c} \le \frac{1}{1+bc/a} = \frac{a}{a+bc} \le \frac{a+\frac{b}{2}}{a + \frac{b}{2} + bc}.$$

This no longer works if $0 < a < 1$, however, and I cannot find an argument which includes this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $\frac{b}{a}=x$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^c}\leq\frac{1+\frac{x}{2}}{1+\frac{x}{2}+cx}$$ or $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=(1+x)^c-1-\frac{2cx}{2+x}.$$
But, $$f'(x)=c(1+x)^{c-1}-2c\cdot\left(\frac{2+x-2}{2+x}\right)'=$$
$$=c\left((1+x)^{c-1}-\frac{4}{(2+x)^2}\right)>c\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{4}{(2+x)^2}\right)=\frac{cx^2}{(1+x)(2+x)^2}>0,$$ which says $f(x)\geq f(0)=0.$